# How to print subtotal amount in qweb odoo

Tags: odoo, qweb

In sales, there is a field named subtotal which holds the value of total amount of all products in line items 'order_line'.

In sale order Qweb report,

Consider if I'm having 12 products showing in first page of my Qweb costing for say 12000, and 6 products in second page of my Qweb costing for say 8000,

I need to print at the end of first page subtotal = 12000 and at the end of second page subtotal = 8000.

Kindly help me to solve this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi have you tried usage of sections (Add Section) in quotation for example? When you use this approach you can see subtotal in section header.

Comment: thanks but i could not get you !

Comment: but i need to do this in report.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried usage of sections (Add Section) in quotation for example? When you use this approach you can see subtotal in section header.

Create quations with sections:
[image]

Print report:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I need. Let me say for example, if report has two pages with ten products in first page and ten products in second page, I need to print the total quantity of first page at its end and to print the total quantity of second page at its end.